# How to pass parameters to manage_shared_memory.construct() in Boost.Interprocess

Tags: c++, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I've stared at the Boost.Interprocess documentation for hours but still haven't been able to figure this out. In the doc, they have [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) of creating a vector in shared memory like so:

```
//Define an STL compatible allocator of ints that allocates from the managed_shared_memory.
//This allocator will allow placing containers in the segment
typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;

//Alias a vector that uses the previous STL-like allocator so that allocates
//its values from the segment
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Create a new segment with given name and size
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
    //Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
    const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
    //Construct a vector named "MyVector" in shared memory with argument alloc_inst
    MyVector *myvector = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);
```

Now, I understand this. What I'm stuck is how to pass a second parameter to `segment.construct()` to specify the number of elements. The interprocess document gives the prototype for `construct()` as

```
MyType *ptr = managed_memory_segment.construct<MyType>("Name") (par1, par2...);
```

but when I try

```
MyVector *myvector = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(100, alloc_inst);
```

I get compilation errors.

My questions are:

1. Who actually gets passed the parameters `par1, par2` from `segment.construct`, the constructor of the object, e.g. `vector`? My understanding is that the template allocator parameter is being passed. Is that correct?
2. How can I add another parameter, in addition to `alloc_inst` that is required by the constructor of the object being created in shared memory?

There's very little information other than the terse Boost docs on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same question on the boost users mailing list and Steven Watanabe [replied](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/03/57284.php) that the problem was simple: std::vector does not have a constructor of the type (size, allocator). Looking at its documentation I see that the constructor is

```
vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

so the correct call should be

```
MyVector *myvector = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(100, 0, alloc_inst);
```

Elementary, my dear, Watson, elementary!